# view website stored on linux pc on any phone

Tags: linux, server, web

I would like to be able to access to my own web site stored on my linux pc anywhere, anytime by connecting my smartphone on my linux pc by wifi to be able to test my website.
I have search on the internet but the only thing I could do is connect my phone to my computer but not going on the stored website.

Is it possible to make the computeur work like a personnal server ?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to Stack Overflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to install a server software, get the ip and port forward.
In depth(With an apache2 lamp server assuming you are using ubuntu):
1. Install the software:
Install apache2(needed), mysql(optional), and php(optional) with

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apache2
sudo apt install mysql-server
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php
```

restart apache with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

2. Move your files to the hosted directory:
You want to move all the files from your website (you can keep sub-folders) into /var/www/html via drag and drop or a mv  command

3. Port forward:
Go into your routers settings, go to port forwarding settings, and make port 80(HTTP) point to your computer's ip.

4. Set up a static ip:
Open up /etc/network/interfaces with a command line or use sudo nautilus and find it. Add the following lines and replace the ():

```
iface (Ethernet or WiFi port) inet static
address (IP address you want on network but the first 3 numbers must be the same as the default gateway)
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway (default gateway a.k.a router settings ip)
```

5. Connect:
If your phone is the same network as your site you can connect to the static ip you created earlier from a web browser. To connect from anywhere find your external ip on a site like http://www.whatsmyip.org/ and connect with any web browser.